# Unable to view image, video after decryption android

Tags: android, encryption, video, imageview, android-videoview

I am using following method to encrypt and decrypt the files. File is getting decrypted properly but I am unable to view Image or video in application. File is opening in gallery and I can view image and watch video clearly. The same I am unable to do in application using Imageview and Videoview

Below is my code :

```
public void run() {
        boolean successful = true;
        operationInProgress = true;
        lastUpdateAtByteNumber = 0;
        totalBytesRead = 0;
        timeOperationStarted = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (operationType == OPERATION_TYPE_ENCRYPTION) {
            completedMessageStringId = R.string.encryption_completed;
        } else {
            completedMessageStringId = R.string.decryption_completed;
        }

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        //get the input stream
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFileName);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            successful = false;
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        //get the output stream
        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            successful = false;
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (inputStream != null && outputStream != null) {
            //call AESCrypt
            try {
                fileSize = inputStream.available();
                AESCrypt aesCrypt = new AESCrypt(password);
                if (operationType == OPERATION_TYPE_ENCRYPTION) {
                    //Encrypt
                    aesCrypt.encrypt(version, inputStream, outputStream);
                } else {
                    //Decrypt
                    aesCrypt.decrypt(fileSize, inputStream, outputStream);
                }
            } catch (GeneralSecurityException gse) {
                successful = false;
                gse.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                successful = false;
                uee.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                successful = false;
            } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                successful = false;
            }
        }

        //close the streams
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                successful = false;
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (outputStream != null) {
            try {
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                successful = false;
            }
        }
        operationInProgress = false;
    }
```

The reference code is https://www.aescrypt.com/download/

AndroidCrypt (AES Crypt compatible) for Android phones (source code)

File getting encrypted and decrypted properly. When I am trying to open the load the file using Imageview for image and videoview for video.

I am using below code to view image

```
File url1 = new File(path to my file);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url1.getAbsolutePath());
objImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

It gives error **"libjpeg error 105 <  Ss=0, Se=63, Ah=0, Al=0> from Incomplete image data"** . or **Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'**
```

For Video I am using below code
getPackageName is name of package
FileProvider I have declared in manifest and also in xml I have menioned fielpath

```
File url1 = new File(path to video file)
videoView.setVideoURI(FileProvider.getUriForFile(
 this, getPackageName(),url1));
```

The same image and video is clearly visible in Gallery application.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: "its not visible in the application" where it is not visible ?

Comment: I am using Imageview to view image and videoview for video. I can view  the filesin gallery but not able to view in application